# How to give two different input files with different extensions for loop script?

Tags: shell

I am writing a for loop to run the loop over list of files. I am using basename to define two different input files but I am getting error like no file or folder found.
I am using the following code and tried shellcheck and no issues detected. I don't know where it is going wrong.

```
for file1 in assemblies/*.fastq; do
   basename=${file1%.fastq}
   file2="$basename"_assembly.fasta
   minimap2 -ax map-ont "$file2" "$file1"  > "$basename"_aln.sam

done
```

I was unable find the mistake in the code.The error is unable to open hour01_assembly.fasta. But I have the file with the same name in the directory. Help me with the issue

modified code

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#set -x

for file1 in assemblies/*.fastq; do
   basename="${file1%.fastq}"
   basename="${basename##*/}"
   file2=assemblies/"$basename"_assembly.fasta
   [ $file2 ] || continue
   echo "f1=$file1", "f2=$file2"
   minimap2 -ax map-ont "$file2" "$file1"  > "$basename"_aln.sam

done
```

It is working now after debugging. Thanks for your useful comments which made the code works.
Thank you

Comment: can you provide the output of `ls -l assemblies/`?

Comment: Yeah sure ```xxx 102964 Dec  9 12:22 hour01_assembly.fasta
xxx Dec 12 11:45 hour01_assembly.fasta.mmi
xxx Dec  9 12:22 hour01_assembly.gfa
xxx Dec  6 15:24 hour01.fastq
xxx Dec  9 13:06 hour02_assembly.fasta
xxx Dec 12 11:45 hour02_assembly.fasta.mmi
xxx Dec  9 13:06 hour02_assembly.gfa
xxx  Dec  6 15:59 hour02.fastq
xxx Dec  9 15:56 hour04_assembly.fasta
xxx Dec 12 11:45 hour04_assembly.fasta.mmi
xxx Dec  9 15:56 hour04_assembly.gfa
xxx Dec  6 16:01 hour04.fastq``` No permission issue.. I just provided only filenames of the output

Comment: Oh, it should be `file2="$basename"_assembly.fasta`

Comment: I tried that as well.. but still the same error..Initially I tried with ``` file2="$basename"_assembly.fasta```. I edited the code in the question

Comment: Your script is fine, but you might have a CR in it; does `grep "$(printf '\r')" script.sh` outputs something?

Comment: No..there are no carriage returns. I am using atom editor and running it in Linux mint. I checked anyway and returned nothing

Comment: "I am getting error like no file or folder found." Quote the exact error messages in your question (as code block). Replace your minimap line with `ls "$file2"`. Does that also fail?

Comment: Test with `echo "f1=$file1, f2=$file2"` and `ls -l "file1" "$file2"`

Comment: Which line produces the error? What is the exact error message? Did you try for debugging to run the script with `set -x` turned on?

Comment: Thank you all guys. @Fravadona . I rectified it after dong some little debugging. There is small mistake in assigning file2. My initial code was correct but don't know why that was not working. Now the same cod is working. I changed the code a bit now